# WCF returned TotalCount -1 but there are Entities, How?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

As You see below , there is a fiddler log. Its a WCF Result and says TotalCount is 
    -1  **(< a: TotalCount > -1 < /a: TotalCount > )**

But there are Entities returned. What does it mean?

**Note:** When I pass parameter take N , then it says TotalCount is 2. But for this Query there is no limitation take 0 or something else.Just an ordering exist.

```
<GetAppointmentsBySearchResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetAppointmentsBySearchResult xmlns:a="DomainServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.or /2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:TotalCount>-1</a:TotalCount>
<a:RootResults xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AHBSBus.Web.DB">
 <b:APT_APPOINTMENT>
<b:APPOINTMENTDATE>2012-05-31T09:30:00</b:APPOINTMENTDATE>
<b:APPOINTMENTENDDATE>2012-05-31T09:45:00</b:APPOINTMENTENDDATE>
<b:APPOINTMENTSTATUS>46814e8a-30ad-4648-a98d-d0134f8eccc4</b:APPOINTMENTSTATUS>
<b:APPOINTMENTTYPE>e4b7c7c5-83f5-4f0c-8e47-5f04d41d9f68</b:APPOINTMENTTYPE>
<b:ARRIVALDATE i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALDATE>
<b:ARRIVALNO i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALNO>
<b:ARRIVALSTATUS i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALSTATUS>
<b:DEPARTUREDATE i:nil="true">
</b:DEPARTUREDATE>
<b:DOCTORID>20376fd9-2411-46c2-8463-72fb995de038</b:DOCTORID>
<b:ENTRYDATE>2012-05-31T13:52:46.617</b:ENTRYDATE>
<b:ENTRYUSERID i:nil="true">
</b:ENTRYUSERID>
<b:ID>0533cb98-618b-4af0-9227-fd14920501e0</b:ID>
<b:ISACTIVE>true</b:ISACTIVE>
<b:ISCLOSED>false</b:ISCLOSED>
<b:NOTE>ok</b:NOTE>
<b:PATIENTCASETYPE>c088796a-6981-4639-9ba9-776eb1906a8f</b:PATIENTCASETYPE>
<b:PATIENTID>c4ae821d-8c26-4002-b5bc-c3fce3d29b6c</b:PATIENTID>
<b:SOCIALSECURITYNO i:nil="true">
</b:SOCIALSECURITYNO>
<b:SUBJECT>NURŞEN GENÇ</b:SUBJECT>
<b:USERID i:nil="true">
</b:USERID>
</b:APT_APPOINTMENT>
<b:APT_APPOINTMENT>
<b:APPOINTMENTDATE>2012-05-31T12:45:00</b:APPOINTMENTDATE>
<b:APPOINTMENTENDDATE>2012-05-31T16:30:00</b:APPOINTMENTENDDATE>
<b:APPOINTMENTSTATUS>46814e8a-30ad-4648-a98d-d0134f8eccc4</b:APPOINTMENTSTATUS>
<b:APPOINTMENTTYPE>ce8482b1-2cc3-41e5-9d54-9f989d50ad66</b:APPOINTMENTTYPE>
<b:ARRIVALDATE i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALDATE>
<b:ARRIVALNO i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALNO>
<b:ARRIVALSTATUS i:nil="true">
</b:ARRIVALSTATUS>
<b:DEPARTUREDATE i:nil="true">
</b:DEPARTUREDATE>
<b:DOCTORID>20376fd9-2411-46c2-8463-72fb995de038</b:DOCTORID>
<b:ENTRYDATE>2012-05-31T13:56:50.773</b:ENTRYDATE>
<b:ENTRYUSERID i:nil="true">
</b:ENTRYUSERID>
<b:ID>bb174e0c-4ebb-4d46-9245-dd88b59d89d1</b:ID>
<b:ISACTIVE>true</b:ISACTIVE>
<b:ISCLOSED>false</b:ISCLOSED>
<b:NOTE>akşama kadar çok uğraştırdın!</b:NOTE>
<b:PATIENTCASETYPE>c088796a-6981-4639-9ba9-776eb1906a8f</b:PATIENTCASETYPE>
<b:PATIENTID>1c108f70-f86b-4a1b-b5bd-2e81ded090bd</b:PATIENTID>
<b:SOCIALSECURITYNO i:nil="true">
</b:SOCIALSECURITYNO>
<b:SUBJECT>Perveen Mahmoodi</b:SUBJECT>
<b:USERID i:nil="true">
</b:USERID>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/data-pager/raddatapager-displays-just-one-page.aspx and found a solution.

I use DomainDataSource and RadDataPager. I just give DomainService Query Method to DomainDataSource's QueryName property. I also added a sorter(In fact I'm revising s.one else's software) on client side. as shown here

```
domainDataSource.SortDescriptors.Add
(new SortDescriptor() { PropertyPath = "APPOINTMENTDATE", 
Direction = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending });
```

Finally I found the solution from the Telerik's link. As I understand the problem is ; In my first Query telerik's components having trouble about sorting. Because my query method running on Server side is a IQueryable. Interestingly if I query 3 times it runs :)

Anyway I added Orderby Operation on Server side and changed return type as IOrderedEnumerable everything returned fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly set the `IncludeTotalCount` property of your query to `true` (before loading it):

```
var query = context.GetAppointmentsBySearchQuery();
query.IncludeTotalCount = true;
context.Load(query)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the point.I searched that Telerik says they manage well IncludeTotalCount property http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/data-pager/raddatapager-displays-just-one-page.aspx . I can't set it because I use DomainDataSource object provided on System.Windows.Controls.DomainServices and I just give QueryName to it. I realized ,had another problem with ordering.