# Include Total Count don't work in RIA

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, wcf-ria-services, collectionview

I try to get DomainCollectionView, but Total Count doesn't include in query:

```
    public DomainCollectionView<sys_log> collView
    {
        get { return (DomainCollectionView<sys_log>)this.GetValue(collViewProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(collViewProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty collViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "collView", typeof(DomainCollectionView<sys_log>), typeof(Journal), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    this._source = this.maindatacontext.sys_logs;
    this._loader = new DomainCollectionViewLoader<sys_log>(this.LoadEntities, this.mdcloaded);
    this._view = new DomainCollectionView<sys_log>(this._loader, this._source);

    private LoadOperation<sys_log> LoadEntities()
    {
        EntityQuery<sys_log> temp = mdc.GetSys_logQuery().OrderBy(order => order.Id).Where(c => c.date > DateFrom.SelectedDate.Value && c.date < DateTo.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)).SortAndPageBy(this._view);
        temp.IncludeTotalCount = true;
        return mdc.Load(temp);
    }


    void mdcloaded(LoadOperation<Web.sys_log> t)
    {
            this.collView = _view;
            //but this _view.TotalItemCount = -1
            dataGrid1.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

dataGrid1 has ItemSource = collView. 
How I can set TotalItemCount or  include it in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422050%28v=vs.91%29) method of your DomainService to get the total count of entities of the query.

```
public class MyDomainService : DomainService{
   protected override int Count<T>(IQueryable<T> query) {
        return query.Count();
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work b'cause you set IncludeTotalCount of query related mdc.

But you look on a dependency propery typed DomainCollectionView < T > .

Does DomainCollectionView implemented from you? Silverlight just supply ICollectionView afaik.If you implemented DomainCollectionView inspect it. Or just try to use collView's Count property.It can be related with implementation of ICollectionView.

```
           var qe=dSrvGD.GetGD_COUNTRYQuery();
            qe.IncludeTotalCount = true;
            dSrvGD.Load(qe).Completed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if ((s as LoadOperation).TotalEntityCount<=0)
                    { 
                        //ASK WHY empty :)
                    }
                }
                ;
```

Description of TotalEntityCount used above is here,

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the total server entity count for the query used by this operation.
    //     Automatic evaluation of the total server entity count requires the property
    //     System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery.IncludeTotalCount on
    //     the query for the load operation to be set to true.
```

I asked a similar question before 
[WCF returned TotalCount -1 but there are Entities, How?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10834160/413032)

Hope helps